# How to use an USB-hokuyo-laserscanner in ros-kinetic

Tags: urg-node, ros-kinetic, hokuyo-node, hokuyo, hokuyo-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I use a USB-hokuyo-laserscanner in ros-kinetic? [hokuyo_node](http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node) seems to be working and pretty well documented (since I'm a beginner using ros, that's important for me, too), but it isn't supported for kinetic. [urg_node](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node), since it's the newer driver, should also do the job, but I've got no idea on how to use the USB and not an ethernet interface. Is it even possible?
Any suggestions and help setting up (in a ros-beginner-friendly way) would be great.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251060/how-to-use-an-usb-hokuyo-laserscanner-in-ros-kinetic/) by [nico_b](https://answers.ros.org/users/28930/nico_b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just got the answer myself.
First I cloned [hokuyo_node (git)](https://github.com/ros-drivers/hokuyo_node) into `~/catkin_ws/src`. Afterwards I called `catkin_make` which resulted in telling me, that the [driver_common package (git)](https://github.com/ros-drivers/driver_common) is missing. Cloning this one, too, and I could run `catkin_make` successfully.
After sourcing `~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` again, I was able to call `rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node`.

---

Originally posted by [nico_b](https://answers.ros.org/users/28930/nico_b/) with karma: 36 on 2017-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the wiki: The [hokuyo_node](http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node) package is depreciated. The [urg_node](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node) package should be used for new projects.

Ethernet is only used if the `ip_address` parameter is set. The package defaults to the serial_port `/dev/ttyACM0`.

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2017-01-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nico_b](https://answers.ros.org/users/28930/nico_b/) on 2017-01-03**:
When calling `rosrun urg_node urg_node` [ros](http://www.ros.org/) is telling me `[ERROR] [1483452523.221964309]: Unknown error connecting to Hokuyo` . What am I doing wrong?
Edit: Somehow it works now. Thanks again :)

**Comment by [nico_b](https://answers.ros.org/users/28930/nico_b/) on 2017-01-04**:
After restarting my system today, it won't work again... Last thing I did yesterday was restarting the system to check whether it works after restart and it did... Why is my sensor not connected today? :(
Btw: Same error as in the post above...

**Comment by [nico_b](https://answers.ros.org/users/28930/nico_b/) on 2017-01-05**:
I found out, I first have to run hokuyo_node. After that some bit (I don't know yet...) is set and therefore I'm able running the urg_node... Any ideas anyone?